# How to apply function vertically in df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to add column values vertically from top to down

```
def add(x,y):
    return x,y

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5]})

df['add'] = df.apply(lambda row : add(row['A'], axis = 1)
```

I tried using apply but its not working

Desired output is basically adding A column values 1+2, 2+3:

```
   A   add
0  1    1
1  2    3
2  3    5
3  4    7
4  5    9
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply [`rolling.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) on a moving window of size 2:

```
df.A.rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum()

0    1.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    7.0
4    9.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
>>> df['add'] = (df + df.shift()).fillna(df)['A']
>>> df
   A  add
0  1  1.0
1  2  3.0
2  3  5.0
3  4  7.0
4  5  9.0
>>>
```